# How to make REST calls to Shopware

Tags: shopware

I enabled the REST call for my admin (cleared the cache and logged out).

I do not understand this instruction:
"You will get a randomly generated API access key, which needs to be included in your API requests for authentication."

In the same page for authentication it says, that i should add this to the header:
Authorization: Basic c2gvcHp3BXJl (this is the encoded username and password)

What should I do with the generated API access key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API-key is used as password. You can check it by accessing /api/orders (e.g.) via Browser. The credentials are the same (username + Apikey).

Shopware provides an example on how to do this in php:

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/#using-the-rest-api-in-your-own-application

https://developers.shopware.com/developers-guide/rest-api/#authentication

The API key will be generated in the backend-user module.

Comment: Thank you, but it is still not written anywhere that the generatd API key will be the password, instead of the admins password.

Comment: Well, the api key is powerful enough, but having that admin password stored somewhere in your application space...